# "Workfile" or "work file"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Our team works on many projects. Each project has a main document (in Excel) that we use to manage all of the work for that project.

Surely, this is a *work file*, but is it also more specifically a *workfile*?

Comment: Being a software developer, I have seen (and used) *work file*, *work-file*, and *workfile* in my time. It is really a matter of style. Choose which you like best, or consult an appropriate style guide if you are writing professionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention Excel specifically, which is a Microsoft product, the correct usage per Microsoft Word would be 'work file'.  Better yet, call them 'Project Files'.